# C++ store reference to an instance of one of two possible classes

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I have a class hierarchy that (simplified) looks like this:

```
struct A {};
struct B : public A {};
struct C {
    A* object;
};
```

I want to store a reference to an object in this hierarchy in some other class, but the object could either be an instance of B or an instance of C that stores an instance of B. Is there an idiomatic way to do this or should I rethink my class structure? FYI, I can't just make B and C a subclass of some new class and then store a reference to that superclass, because they have conceptually different purposes and contain different fields and methods.

Comment: How about `std::variant`?

Comment: @kiner_shah I looked it up, looks like it would get the job done, but it seems kinda fancy and potentially slow. Thoughts?

Comment: You should rethink your class structure. If they have *conceptually different purposes and contain different fields and methods*, you shouldn't be trying to store a reference to those totally independent classes as your sample indicates. How does code that uses `struct C` know what it can do with the unknown type `A`? What purpose will `A` serve, since you don't know what fields and methods that unknown object contains?

Comment: @KenWhite Sounds about right, I will attempt to do that.

Comment: To clarify, the purpose of C was to wrap A so that i can change its memory location while maintaining a reference to the updated location in another class. To be honest I forget why I didn't use a double pointer and I'm pretty sure that would work so I will do that instead.

Comment: `B` and `C` are not in a common hierarchy. `std::variant<B, C>` may be the way to go. You _can_ make a common superclass of B and C, possibly using multiple inheritance and inheriting only from what they share, such as `EitherInheritsFromAOrContainsA`. The interface would declare a method returning `A&`, implemented as `*object` in `C` and as `*this` in `B`.

Comment: If you "can't just make B and C a subclass of some new class" then your example code is oversimplified - because you technically __can__, so you haven't satisfactorily explained why _you_ can't do so in your situation.  i.e.: maybe explain your specific situation in a bit more detail.

Comment: @ERSUCC you cannot assume that a  feature of the standard library is slow without even trying it out first. If it were, it wouldn’t even be in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) is exactly what you are seeking. Seeing that `B` and `C` are not related in any way, polymorphism can’t help here. So do:

```cpp
std::variant<B, C> b_or_c;
                   b_or_c = B{};

C value;
try
{ value = std::get<C>(b_or_c); }
catch (const std::bad_variant_access& exception)
{ std::cout << exception.what(); }
```

These are also possible:

```cpp
std::variant<B*, const C&> b_or_c;
auto& value = std::get<const C&>(b_or_c);
```